# How to specify the filter condition with spark DataFrameReader API for a table?

Tags: apache-spark

I was reading about spark on databricks documentation https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html#partition-pruning-1

It says

> When the table is scanned, Spark pushes down the filter predicates
>   involving the partitionBy keys. In that case, Spark avoids reading
>   data that doesn’t satisfy those predicates. For example, suppose you
>   have a table  that is partitioned by `<date>`. A query
>   such as `SELECT max(id) FROM <example-data> WHERE date = '2010-10-10'`
>   reads only the data files containing tuples whose date value matches
>   the one specified in the query.

How can I specify such filter condition in DataFrameReader API while reading a table?

Answer (score 0):

As spark is lazily evaluated when your read the data using dataframe reader it is just added as a stage in the underlying DAG.

Now when you run SQL query over the data it is also added as another stage in the DAG.

And when you apply any action over the dataframe, then the  DAG is evaluated and all the stages are optimized by catalyst optimized which in the end generated the most cost effective physical plan.

At the time of DAG evaluation predicate conditions are pushed down and only the required data is read into the memory.

Answer (score -2):

DataFrameReader is created (available) exclusively using SparkSession.read.
That means it is created when the following code is executed (example of csv file load)

```
val df = spark.read.csv("path1,path2,path3")
```

Spark provides a pluggable Data Provider Framework (Data Source API) to rollout your own datasource. Basically, it provides interfaces that can be implemented for reading/writing to your custom datasource. That's where generally the partition pruning and predicate filter pushdowns are implemented.

Databricks spark supports many built-in datasources (along with predicate pushdown and partition pruning capabilities) as per https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/index.html.

So, if the need is to load data from JDBC table and specify filter conditions, please see the following example

```
// Note: The parentheses are required.
val pushdown_query = "(select * from employees where emp_no < 10008) emp_alias"
val df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

Please refer to more details here
https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html